# Can we use Azure logic apps as an alternative for SQL broker

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to migrate existing SQL broker to Azure SQL. 
Can we use Azure Logic apps to perform the same functionality.
Suggestions , Please.

Comment: Sure, maybe.  But you'll get a better answer if you include some detail on what the app actually does with/in SSB.

Comment: Surely , I will add more comments

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,you can do it using combination of Azure Web job(read message from source database or application) and Azure Service bus (for queuing and messaging) and Logic App (process data and store in to final database)

please see below diagram for understading

[image]

Comment: for read data from distributed  database and add into queue we need to use it its one kind of function which read data and add into queue

Comment: yeah but I guess logic app can also do it for you... no ? how your webjob will be triggered ???

Comment: yes, using two logic app we  can also do it one from enqueue and another for dequeue, we can replace azure web job with enqueue logic app

Comment: Sorry I dont want to be meant, try to explain different use case so it will be a valuable anwer :-)

Comment: ok if you have two distributed application which database is mongo db , and in the day end you want to fetch all records from both database and want to store in your master database (SQL database) so in logic app there is no connector for mongo db so we can create one web API which enqueue data in queue and you can dequeue at logic app side and then store it in to SQL database

Comment: Thanks  Sahadev , but I have a question here , Cant we directly use only 1 logic apps to enque and deque the message and then  execute an action as trigger to further downstream database.